# Calling List<string>[] Select(string query) in C# class

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I'm learning C# but i don't find the info of my problem. I've find this piece of code on the web.
It's a function in a class. But i don't know how to call it, to execute it.

I never had this type of function " List[] Select(string query) "

Someone can help me ?

Thanks for your answer ,

```
  class DBConnect
  {

// ------- Code hided  for Open/close mysql connection // 

      public List<string>[] Select(string query)
      {

          //string query = "SELECT id, aff_client, entreprise, ip_client FROM liste_machines ORDER BY entreprise ASC, aff_client ASC";

          //Create a list to store the result
          List<string>[] list = new List<string>[3];
          list[0] = new List<string>();
          list[1] = new List<string>();
          list[2] = new List<string>();

          //Open connection
          if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
          {
              //Create Command
              MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
              //Create a data reader and Execute the command
              MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

              //Read the data and store them in the list
              while (dataReader.Read())
              {
                  list[0].Add(dataReader["id"] + "");
                  list[1].Add(dataReader["aff_client"] + "");
                  list[2].Add(dataReader["entreprise"] + "");
                  list[3].Add(dataReader["ip_client"] + "");

              }

              //close Data Reader
              dataReader.Close();

              //close Connection
              this.CloseConnection();

              //return list to be displayed
              return list;
          }
          else
          {
              return list;
          }


      }

}
```

Comment: Something like this: `List<string> myList = Select("myquery");` On another note, no need to set your list to a specific size, that list will grow and shrink as needed.

Comment: ^ is for in the class, but outside of it you would need to create an instance of `DBConnect` and then call it: `List<string> myStrings = instance.Select("your query");`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's really helpfull !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question that how to call the method (function) select which is in DBConnect class, the code will be something like as below.

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public void Mymethod()
        {
            DBConnect db = new DBConnect();//Object creation
            List<string>[] result = db.Select("MyQuery");//Method (Function) calling
            foreach (List<string> item in result)//To access each List<string> from the array of List<string>
            {   // Do something with item if required

                foreach (string innerItem in item) // To access each string from the List<string>
                {
                    //Do something with innerItem
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

The object name at `List<string>[] list = new List<string>[3];` could be something like arrayData instead of list, as if we use list as object name it could be some what misleading us.

Answer (score -1):

You can call `Select` function using the `DBConnect` class object.

```cs
var dbObject = new DBConnect();
string query = "Your query here";
List<string>[] selectOutput = dbObject.Select(query);
```

Below is how you use the variable of type `List<string>[]`. It is an `array` of type `List<string>`

```cs
List<string>[] test = new List<string>[2];
test[0] = new List<string> { "ABC", "DEF" };
test[1] = new List<string> { "GHI", "JKL" };
Console.WriteLine(test[0][0]);
Console.WriteLine(test[0][1]);
Console.WriteLine(test[1][0]);
Console.WriteLine(test[1][1]);
```

**Output:**

> ABC 
>   DEF 
>   GHI 
>   JKL

Comment: You're welcome. Please upvote if the answer has helped.

Comment: I did, not enough reputation !

Comment: No worries . Glad it helped